# How can I use pop to print an array backwards in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, reverse

I am beginning to learn Perl, but am having an issue printing an array in reverse order with the pop command. I want to make this work with pop and not with other commands like reverse, or using techniques like reverse indices. Whenever I run this loop with the array, @anotherArray = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5); I only end up getting " 5, 4, 3" as a result. Am I doing something wrong with my logic or syntax?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $#anotherArray + 1; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0)
        {
                print "Third way: ";
        }
        $temp = pop @anotherArray;
        print "$temp ";
}
```

Comment: its because as you pop an item off the array you are reducing the size of it by one, so when you get to 3 the array only has two items in it and stops the for loop

Comment: `print reverse @array`

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (-1,0,1..5);

while (@array) {
    my $e = pop @array;
    print "$e\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the array is shrinking while you are popping from it, so the limit for `$i` in the loop is getting smaller.

The best way is to use a `while` loop to keep popping from the array until it is empty.

I'm not sure what the *"Third way"* part is supposed to mean, but you can just print that outside the loop.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @anotherArray = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

print "Third way: ";

while (@anotherArray) {
  print pop @anotherArray;
}
```

**output**

```
Third way: 54321
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of doing it, since it is Perl anyways:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @anotherArray = ( 1 .. 5 );

print pop @anotherArray while @anotherArray;
```

it just does what is says:

print the popped-of-element from anotherArray, as long as there is a number of elements in anotherArray.

This way of doing loops or placing conditionals like `if` or `unless` are fine for a single line of code, but highly frown upon when it is a whole `BLOCK` of code.

Comment: That's the solution I was just about to post. Well, almost. I would have omitted the unnecessary parentheses around the `while` condition :-)

Comment: Will take that into account next time, silly enough, I leave them of in `if` and `unless`. will edit this now. (should I drop the semi colon as well, it's the last statement :-D

Comment: Never drop the semi-colon. There's always a chance that it won't remain the last statement :-)

Comment: @DaveCross Funny enough, [perldoc perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) says that you "should" omit it. `Semicolon omitted in "short" one-line BLOCK.` Just trivia since I happened to read it the other day. I would not leave out semi-colon either.

Comment: But that isn't a one-line block. Larry is talking about the semi-colon in (for example) `do { some_stuff(); } while $some_flag`.

Comment: Oh, you mean the last semi-colon in the file? I assumed you were talking about a previous edit. My bad.

Comment: it's such a bad idea, like Dave said; I wouldn't do that anyway… except than, that I accidentally did in my test script. I only to found out when I copy pasted it from my .pl file into this stack overflow edit window, wondering where my semi-colon had gone, as if I hadn't selected it when copying… it wasn't there in the source either ;-(